# Python Selenium Cannot find ID in website

Tags: python, selenium

Why is it whenever I try to find "uxStartDateDecisionTextBox" it says it cannot find the ID. On the website they have another ID called "BodyPlaceHolder_uxTextSearchKeywords" and whenever I try to find that ID it works perfectly fine. What is the issue? I tried googling it but nothing helped, so I am resorting to asking on here.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://www.fareham.gov.uk/casetrackerplanning/applicationsearch.aspx"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Goten\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_id("lnkAllowCookies").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("BodyPlaceHolder_uxLinkButtonShowAdvancedSearch").click()

driver.find_element_by_id("uxStartDateDecisionTextBox").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("uxStartDateDecisionTextBox").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("uxStartDateDecisionTextBox").send_keys("01/08/2018")

driver.find_element_by_id("uxStopDateDecisionTextBox").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("uxStopDateDecisionTextBox").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("uxStopDateDecisionTextBox").send_keys("30/08/2018")

driver.find_element_by_id("BodyPlaceHolder_uxButtonSearch").click()
```

Error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Goten\Desktop\sel.py", line 11, in <module>
  driver.find_element_by_id("uxStartDateDecisionTextBox").click()
File "C:\Users\Goten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 359, in find_element_by_id
  return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
File "C:\Users\Goten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 966, in find_element
  'value': value})['value']
File "C:\Users\Goten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
  self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\Goten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
  raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
  selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"uxStartDateDecisionTextBox"}
(Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Comment: are you adding enough wait time for item to be available before clicking on it?

Comment: Mono has fixed it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before one clicks on the `'Advanced Search'` link, the entire `Advanced Search Form` is not at all present in the DOM. After clicking on the link, the entire form is loaded in the DOM at runtime. So I can't think of anything other than this being a synchronization issue.

Try adding a step before

`"driver.find_element_by_id("uxStartDateDecisionTextBox").click()"` that pauses the execution for a second or so. If after that, Selenium is able to locate the element, you can be pretty sure that this is a synchronization problem. Then you can opt for some kind of explicit waits to improve your execution speed.